# ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias

Tags: apache-pig, apache-tez

> $ pig -z tez grunt> emp = LOAD '/emp.csv, /tmp/emp/part-m-00000' using
>   PigStorage(',') as (id:int, name:chararray, disg:chararray, sal:long,
>   loc:chararray); 2015-12-16 21:30:21,706 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is
>   deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS grunt> dump emp;

Failed!

```
DAG PigLatin:DefaultJobName-0_scope-8:
       ApplicationId: null                                                                                                
  TotalLaunchedTasks: -1                                                                                                  
       FileBytesRead: -1                                                                                                  
    FileBytesWritten: -1                                                                                                  
       HdfsBytesRead: 0                                                                                                   
    HdfsBytesWritten: 0
```

Input(s):

Output(s):

```
2015-12-16 21:31:00,745 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias emp
Details at logfile: /tmp/pig-err.log
```

Comment: Does it work on regular MR (not TEZ)? What are the contents of the log file? Are you sure those files are in HDFS?

Comment: Yes, they work on MR, but not working on TEZ while DUMP relarion, I am sure they are on HDFS,

Comment: Does that mean that the dump works on MR but not on TEZ? What is the output of a `describe emp;` instead of the dump?

Comment: Yes it is working on MR

Comment: Please help me on this

Comment: Not sure if this answer is sufficient as you claim the code in general works, but perhaps this still helps [ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34495085/error-1066-unable-to-open-iterator-for-alias-in-pig-generic-solution) here is a [generic solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34495086/983722).